# imakeidx: Hyperlink both the index title and the page number

Tags: indexing, links

I am creating my index using makeindex. Using hyperref, the page numbers within the index are correctly linked to the corresponding page. However, I also would like the index title (i.e. the keyword) to link to the corresponding page. I was not able to find a corresponding option in the imakeidx documentation.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam rutrum aliquet elit in pellentesque. Proin nulla eros, consequat nec convallis vel, vulputate vitae purus\index{purus}. Pellentesque consequat euismod sapien, ac porttitor diam laoreet id. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus\index{senectus} et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed vehicula magna orci, nec congue sem congue ac. Sed fringilla aliquam interdum. Nullam quis commodo massa.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This prints an index as follows: [image]

However, I would also like to link the keywords "purus" and "senectus".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't think this is a feature that `hyperref` supports.

Comment: even if this feature can be provided, if an entry has more than one page reference, the terxt of the entry can't reliably be linked.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that a keyword can be linked to multiple pages. This, of course, makes my request kind of impossible.